# Java program continues to run (in background) even after last statement in main

Tags: java, linux, bash, background-process

**Background**

I am having a simple java program which reads data from std input. I am executing it though from a bash script `executer.sh`

```
python2 readLines.py | tee logfile |  java MsgReader
```

`readLines.py` reads data from a file line by line and throws it on the stdout

*MsgReader.java*

```
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;

public void process() {
    String msg = ""; 
    BufferedReader stdinReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)

    Producer producer = new Producer();//it takes config file as parameter which is not related to the question here

    try {
         while ((msg = stdinReader.readLine()) != null) {
              producer.send(message);
         }   
         stdinReader.close();
     } catch (IOException|FailedToSendMessageException e) {
            System.out.println("Send message failed!");
            e.printStackTrace();
     }   
}   

public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException,IOException {
    try{
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println("Start : " + now);
        process();// Continuously reads logs
        now = new Date();
        System.out.println("After : " + now);
    } catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }   
}
```

**Execution**

`./executer.sh &` : executing in the background

**Problem**

After reading all the lines `readLines.py` ends, but `executer.sh` and `MsgReader.java` are stll executing as verified by `ps` command. The statement `System.out.println("After : " + now);` os recorded in the log file, indicating the program has reached the last statement in the main function.

How to terminate the java program and bash script gracefully.

I do not want to add `System.exit()` here.

**Platform**

*CentOS release 6.7 (Final)*

*java 1.7.0_95*

*python 2.7.6*

Comment: What does `process` do? It could be pretty relevant, especially since it sounds like it's probably an asynchronous task executor of some type. Consider checking out [mcve].

Comment: what is p? please show the code

Comment: What if you run it in the foreground?

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve does not have anything to do with process method AFAIK. That part is working fine. I was more interested in trying to understand a process running in background need special treatment as far as completion is concerned. The `process` method has more sophisticated logic nonetheless I have tried simplifying it. Let's see it that helps.

Comment: @Jim it is *now* (earlier there was no code whatsoever). Go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not close the Producer. From the Javadoc for `KafkaProducer` (the implementation of `Producer`):

> The producer consists of a pool of buffer space that holds records that haven't yet been transmitted to the server as well as a background I/O thread that is responsible for turning these records into requests and transmitting them to the cluster. Failure to close the producer after use will leak these resources.

The background thread is still running and will prevent the process from ending until you close the `Producer`, preferably in a `finally` block after the `try`/`catch`.  Also, that `stdinReader.close();` belongs in the `finally` as well.